# Android telnet robust communication example

Tags: android, sockets, networking, client, telnet

I want to develop a simple Android application which tries to telnet to a remote port, then waits until it gets data which is not more than 4 decimal numbers like:

10,20,30,40

then closes connection to the server and processes these data. It seems to be simple but in reality I have no clue where to get started (haven't write any android apps yet). This communication has to be robust because the phone often loses connectivity (hops on and off on different 3G/Wifi networks), it has to detect if there is no connection and not even trying to connect. It cannot go into endless loop and exhaust the cpu.

Anybody know good examples (GUI preferred) what I can use to get started with this project?

Thank you